# center align the image

Tags: css, image, html, alignment

How do I center align the image to vertically and horizontally to the div.

I need to get this without fixing height or padding because the image sizes are not constant so it should be flexible with all the images.

Here is my trail
http://jsfiddle.net/yHdAx/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey now you can used to `table-cell` properties in your div as like this

**live demo** http://jsfiddle.net/yHdAx/3/

**HTML**

```
 <div style="height:800px; background-color:#CCC">
<div class="test">
<img src="http://static.clickbd.com/global/classified/item_img/607724_0_original.jpg" />
</div>
```

**Css**

```
  .test{
background-color:red;
height:600px; display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}
.test img{
max-width:50%;

}
```

more info http://www.brunildo.org/test/img_center.html

Answer (score 2):

To center align an image, you have to set it's display to block, and then the left and right margins to auto. I also did this with the top and bottom margins, in the new code example. Here is the code required to make this work:

**CSS**

```
.test {
    background-color:#999;
    height:60%;
    display:block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding-top: 25%;
    padding-botton: 25%;
}

.test img {
    max-width:50%;
    vertical-align: ;
    display: block;
    margin: auto auto auto auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div style="height:800px; background-color:#CCC">
    <div class="test">
        <img src="http://static.clickbd.com/global/classified/item_img/607724_0_original.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply `display:block` to the image and set its margins to `auto`.

```
.test {
    background-color:#999;
    padding: 50px 0;
}

.test img {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Here is the fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/yHdAx/5/

Answer (score 0):

What if you don't set a height on the containing div, would the desig break then?

To center the image just use

```
.test img {
    display:block; 
    width:25%; 
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to play with only one div

```
div  {
    display:table-cell;
    background:red;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}
```

I hope this will also help you :- http://jsbin.com/ihunuq/3/edit

Answer (score 0):

You can use position: absolute.
Something like that: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yHdAx/11/).

```
.test{
  background-color:#999;
  height:60%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.test img{
  max-width:50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```